Webview with dynamic message handler name
A web view needs to send message to the iOS Native WKWebView, using below syntax.
window.webkit.messageHandlers.countryListHandler.postMessage("data")
Is there a way this can be called dynamically? Post Message can be dynamic but can message Handler name be dynamic as well?
func callFunction(handlerName, body) {
window.webkit.messageHandlers.{handlerName}.postMessage(body);
}


After couple of tries found that window.webkit.messageHandlers is an associative object or dictionary so you can access the value like a dictionary key.
The function needs to be called like this with square brackets not the Curley brackets.
func callFunction(handlerName, body) {
window.webkit.messageHandlers.[handlerName].postMessage(body);
}

